# Django <a href="..."> link redirect me inside my app

Tags: html, django, url

I have this basic blog app  https://github.com/Belonias/blog

and for example

```
<li><a href="www.github.com/Belonias"><img alt="github" src="{% static "img/test1/github.png" %}"></a></li>
```

redirects me inside the app and not the actual link.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What if you do `<a href="https://www.github.com/Belonias">`?

Comment: Yeap it did the job. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the protocol in `href` attribute, otherwise I believe it is referring to the relative url of current url. If your url is:

```
http://test.com
```

your `href` would give you

```
http://test.com/www.github.com/Belonias
```

that's why it redirects you to your app instead of going to github.

Answer (score 0):

use Urlize

```
{{var_url|urlize}}
```

About urlize https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize